# Qt Set button color from another class

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I've spent couple days on doing this, but every solution that I tried just didn't work.

I have colorPicker where I pick a color. The ColorPicker is a class. I have button in another class called ToolWindow. I want to change color of button in class ToolWindow after picking a color in class ColorPicker.

Here is some code:

toolWindow.h

```
#ifndef TOOLWINDOW_H
#define TOOLWINDOW_H

#include <QDialog>
#include "colorpicker.h"
//#include "mainwindow.h"

namespace Ui {
class ToolWindow;
}

class ToolWindow : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ToolWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ToolWindow();
void setColor(QColor color);


private slots:
    void on_penTool_clicked();
    void on_rectTool_clicked();
    void on_selectTool_clicked();
    void on_circleTool_clicked();
    void on_lineTool_clicked();
    void on_colorButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::ToolWindow *ui;
    ColorPicker colorPicker;
    QColor nColor;

};

#endif // TOOLWINDOW_H
```

toolWindow.cpp

```
#include "toolwindow.h"
#include "ui_toolwindow.h"
#include "colorpicker.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QMouseEvent>

ToolWindow::ToolWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ToolWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

ToolWindow::~ToolWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void ToolWindow::on_penTool_clicked()
{
    mSelection = 1;
}

void ToolWindow::on_rectTool_clicked()
{
    mSelection = 2;
}

void ToolWindow::on_selectTool_clicked()
{
    mSelection = 0;
}

void ToolWindow::on_circleTool_clicked()
{
    mSelection = 3;
}

void ToolWindow::on_lineTool_clicked()
{
    mSelection = 4;
}

void ToolWindow::on_colorButton_clicked()
{
    colorPicker.show();
}

void ToolWindow::setColor(QColor color)
{
    //ui->colorButton->setPalette(color);
    //nColor = color;
}
```

colorPicker.h

```
#ifndef COLORPICKER_H
#define COLORPICKER_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QColor>
//#include "mainwindow.h"

namespace Ui {
class ColorPicker;
}

class ColorPicker : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ColorPicker(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ColorPicker();

    QPalette palete;

private slots:
    void on_buttonBox_rejected();
    void onColorChanged();
    void onCMYKChanged();

    void on_buttonBox_accepted();

private:
    Ui::ColorPicker *ui;
    double min(double a,double b,double c);

    QColor mColor;
    double k,c,m,y;
    int r,g,b;

signals:
    void colorChanged(QColor arg);

};

#endif // COLORPICKER_H
```

colorPicker.cpp

```
#include "colorpicker.h"
#include "ui_colorpicker.h"
#include "toolwindow.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QPalette>

ColorPicker::ColorPicker(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ColorPicker)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->redSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),SLOT(onColorChanged()));
    connect(ui->greenSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),SLOT(onColorChanged()));
    connect(ui->blueSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),SLOT(onColorChanged()));
    connect(ui->blackSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),SLOT(onCMYKChanged()));
    connect(ui->yellowSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),SLOT(onCMYKChanged()));
    connect(ui->magentaSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),SLOT(onCMYKChanged()));
    connect(ui->cyanSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),SLOT(onCMYKChanged()));
    //connect(this,SIGNAL(colorChanged(QColor)),toolWindow,SLOT(setColor(QColor)));
    onColorChanged();

}

ColorPicker::~ColorPicker()
{
    delete ui;
}

void ColorPicker::on_buttonBox_rejected()
{
    this->close();
}

double ColorPicker::min(double a,double b,double c)
{
    double tmp;
    if(a>b)
    {
        if(a>c)
            tmp = a;
        else
            tmp = c;
    }
    else
    {
        if(b>c)
            tmp = b;
        else
            tmp = c;
    }
    return tmp;
}

void ColorPicker::onColorChanged()
{
    int q1,q2,q3;
    mColor.setRgb(ui->redSlider->value(),ui->greenSlider->value(),ui->blueSlider->value());
    q1=ui->redSlider->value();
    q2=ui->greenSlider->value();
    q3=ui->blueSlider->value();
    palete = ui->widget->palette();
    palete.setColor(QPalette::Window, mColor);
    ui->widget->setPalette(palete);
    emit colorChanged(mColor);
    k=min(q1,q2,q3);
    c=(1-ui->redSlider->value()-k)/(1-k);
    m=(1-ui->greenSlider->value()-k)/(1-k);
    y=(1-ui->blueSlider->value()-k)/(1-k);
    ui->blackSlider->setValue(k);
    ui->cyanSlider->setValue(c);
    ui->magentaSlider->setValue(m);
    ui->yellowSlider->setValue(y);

}
void ColorPicker::onCMYKChanged()
{
    mColor.setRgb(ui->redSlider->value(),ui->greenSlider->value(),ui->blueSlider->value());
    palete = ui->widget->palette();
    palete.setColor(QPalette::Window, mColor);
    ui->widget->setPalette(palete);
    emit colorChanged(mColor);
}

void ColorPicker::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    //QPalette pal = ui->widget->palette();
    //pal.setColor(QPalette::Window, mColor);
    //Ui::ToolWindow
    //MainWindow::MainWindow().mColor.setRgb(ui->redSlider->value(),ui->greenSlider->value(),ui->blueSlider->value());
            //mColor.setRgb(ui->redSlider->value(),ui->greenSlider->value(),ui->blueSlider->value());
}
```

mainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "toolwindow.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class QPainter;
class QImage;
extern int mSelection;


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    ToolWindow toolWindow;
    QColor mColor;

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QPainter *mPainter;
    QImage *mImage;
    QPixmap mPix;
    QPoint mBegin;
    QPoint mEnd;

    QRect mRect;
    QLine mLine;
    bool drawStarted;
    bool mPressed;
    int mSize;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QImage>

int mSelection = 0;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mPix = QPixmap(400,400);
    mPix.fill(Qt::white);
    mPressed = false;
    drawStarted = false;
    mColor = QColor(Qt::black);
    mSize = 2;


    toolWindow.setWindowFlags(Qt::SubWindow | Qt::WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus);
    toolWindow.show();

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawPixmap(0,0,mPix);

    QPen pen(mColor);
    pen.setCapStyle(Qt::RoundCap);
    pen.setWidth(mSize);
    painter.setPen(pen);

    if(mPressed)
    {
        if(mSelection == 2)
            painter.drawRect(mRect);
        else if(mSelection == 4) {
            painter.drawLine(mLine);
        }
        drawStarted = true;
    } else if (drawStarted){
        QPainter tempPainter(&mPix);
        tempPainter.setPen(pen);
        if(mSelection == 2)
            tempPainter.drawRect(mRect);
        else if(mSelection == 4) {
            tempPainter.drawLine(mLine);
        }
        painter.drawPixmap(0,0,mPix);
    }
    painter.end();
}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    mPressed = true;
    mBegin = event->pos();
    if(mSelection == 2){
        mRect.setTopLeft(event->pos());
        mRect.setBottomRight(event->pos());
    }
    else if(mSelection == 4){
        mLine.setP1(event->pos());
        mLine.setP2(event->pos());
    }
}

void MainWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QPen pen(mColor);
    pen.setCapStyle(Qt::RoundCap);
    pen.setWidth(mSize);
    switch(mSelection)
    {
    case 1:
        {
            QPainter penPainter(&mPix);
            penPainter.setPen(pen);
            mEnd = event->pos();
            penPainter.drawLine(mBegin, mEnd);
            mBegin = mEnd;
            update();
            break;
        }
    case 2:
        {
            mRect.setBottomRight(event->pos());
            update();
            break;
        }
    case 4:
        {
            mLine.setP2(event->pos());
            update();
            break;
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{

    mPressed = false;
    update();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.setStyle("fusion");

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();


    return a.exec();
}
```

colorPicker.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>ColorPicker</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="ColorPicker">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>355</width>
    <height>293</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>9</x>
     <y>9</y>
     <width>16</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>R</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>40</y>
     <width>16</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>G</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>16</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>B</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QSlider" name="redSlider">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>131</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="maximum">
    <number>255</number>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QSlider" name="greenSlider">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>40</y>
     <width>131</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="maximum">
    <number>255</number>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QSlider" name="blueSlider">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>131</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="maximum">
    <number>255</number>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QSpinBox" name="redSpinbox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>170</x>
     <y>8</y>
     <width>51</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="maximum">
    <number>255</number>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QSpinBox" name="greenSpinbox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>170</x>
     <y>40</y>
     <width>51</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="maximum">
    <number>255</number>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QSpinBox" name="blueSpinbox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>170</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>51</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="maximum">
    <number>255</number>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>130</y>
     <width>16</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>K</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>160</y>
     <width>16</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Y</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_6">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>190</y>
     <width>16</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>M</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QSlider" name="blackSlider">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>130</y>
     <width>131</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="maximum">
    <number>255</number>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QSlider" name="yellowSlider">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>160</y>
     <width>131</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="maximum">
    <number>255</number>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QSlider" name="magentaSlider">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>190</y>
     <width>131</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="maximum">
    <number>255</number>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QDialogButtonBox" name="buttonBox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>260</y>
     <width>156</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="standardButtons">
    <set>QDialogButtonBox::Cancel|QDialogButtonBox::Ok</set>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>230</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>101</width>
     <height>271</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>0</width>
     <height>76</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="baseSize">
    <size>
     <width>0</width>
     <height>0</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="autoFillBackground">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_7">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>220</y>
     <width>16</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>C</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QSlider" name="cyanSlider">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>220</y>
     <width>131</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="maximum">
    <number>255</number>
   </property>
   <property name="singleStep">
    <number>1</number>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QSpinBox" name="blackSpinbox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>170</x>
     <y>130</y>
     <width>51</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="maximum">
    <number>255</number>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QSpinBox" name="yellowSpinbox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>170</x>
     <y>160</y>
     <width>51</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="maximum">
    <number>255</number>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QSpinBox" name="magentaSpinbox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>170</x>
     <y>190</y>
     <width>51</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="maximum">
    <number>255</number>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QSpinBox" name="cyanSpinbox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>170</x>
     <y>220</y>
     <width>51</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="maximum">
    <number>255</number>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>buttonBox</sender>
   <signal>accepted()</signal>
   <receiver>ColorPicker</receiver>
   <slot>accept()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>185</x>
     <y>291</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>157</x>
     <y>274</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>buttonBox</sender>
   <signal>rejected()</signal>
   <receiver>ColorPicker</receiver>
   <slot>reject()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>185</x>
     <y>290</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>286</x>
     <y>274</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>redSlider</sender>
   <signal>valueChanged(int)</signal>
   <receiver>redSpinbox</receiver>
   <slot>setValue(int)</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>163</x>
     <y>23</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>193</x>
     <y>22</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>redSpinbox</sender>
   <signal>valueChanged(int)</signal>
   <receiver>redSlider</receiver>
   <slot>setValue(int)</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>185</x>
     <y>11</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>163</x>
     <y>16</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>greenSlider</sender>
   <signal>valueChanged(int)</signal>
   <receiver>greenSpinbox</receiver>
   <slot>setValue(int)</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>163</x>
     <y>52</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>187</x>
     <y>53</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>greenSpinbox</sender>
   <signal>valueChanged(int)</signal>
   <receiver>greenSlider</receiver>
   <slot>setValue(int)</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>182</x>
     <y>46</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>163</x>
     <y>46</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>blueSlider</sender>
   <signal>valueChanged(int)</signal>
   <receiver>blueSpinbox</receiver>
   <slot>setValue(int)</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>163</x>
     <y>80</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>187</x>
     <y>79</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>blueSpinbox</sender>
   <signal>valueChanged(int)</signal>
   <receiver>blueSlider</receiver>
   <slot>setValue(int)</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>179</x>
     <y>81</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>163</x>
     <y>78</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>cyanSpinbox</sender>
   <signal>valueChanged(int)</signal>
   <receiver>cyanSlider</receiver>
   <slot>setValue(int)</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>178</x>
     <y>227</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>144</x>
     <y>225</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>cyanSlider</sender>
   <signal>valueChanged(int)</signal>
   <receiver>cyanSpinbox</receiver>
   <slot>setValue(int)</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>143</x>
     <y>236</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>193</x>
     <y>241</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>magentaSlider</sender>
   <signal>valueChanged(int)</signal>
   <receiver>magentaSpinbox</receiver>
   <slot>setValue(int)</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>144</x>
     <y>202</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>170</x>
     <y>202</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>magentaSpinbox</sender>
   <signal>valueChanged(int)</signal>
   <receiver>magentaSlider</receiver>
   <slot>setValue(int)</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>191</x>
     <y>191</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>143</x>
     <y>195</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>yellowSlider</sender>
   <signal>valueChanged(int)</signal>
   <receiver>yellowSpinbox</receiver>
   <slot>setValue(int)</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>146</x>
     <y>171</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>185</x>
     <y>175</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>yellowSpinbox</sender>
   <signal>valueChanged(int)</signal>
   <receiver>yellowSlider</receiver>
   <slot>setValue(int)</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>181</x>
     <y>168</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>122</x>
     <y>170</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>blackSlider</sender>
   <signal>valueChanged(int)</signal>
   <receiver>blackSpinbox</receiver>
   <slot>setValue(int)</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>148</x>
     <y>142</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>183</x>
     <y>143</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>blackSpinbox</sender>
   <signal>valueChanged(int)</signal>
   <receiver>blackSlider</receiver>
   <slot>setValue(int)</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>185</x>
     <y>136</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>143</x>
     <y>136</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```

I reached limit in chars used in this post.

Here is link to whole project: http://uploadfile.pl/pokaz/1252644---svem.html

I tried solutions with signals and slot, but it's not working for me - I guess that I do something wrong.

Comment: Share the .ui and the main.cpp

Comment: I've added link to download my project.

Comment: Do you want the color of the button to change when the ColorPicker color changes or when the ColorPicker OK button is pressed?

Comment: When Button ok is pressed. I don't know how to give color information to object of another class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the values of some property with a `QDialog` after pressing the button that accepts the dialogue, it is not necessary to use signals. What you must do is execute the `exec()` function that generates a main loop so no line is executed after it, this function returns the accepted and rejected status that we can check with Accepted and Rejected, respectively.

But for this you must create the getter method that will be called color in ColorPicker:

***.h**

```
public:
    QColor color() const;
```

***.cpp**

```
QColor ColorPicker::color() const
{
    return mColor;
}
```

Then we rewrite the slot `on_colorButton_clicked` and the function `setColor` of `ToolWindow`:

```
void ToolWindow::on_colorButton_clicked()
{
    if(colorPicker.exec() == ColorPicker::Accepted){
        setColor(colorPicker.color());
    }
}

void ToolWindow::setColor(QColor color)
{
    ui->colorButton->setPalette(color);
}
```

The complete code can be found at the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/46989493/Pajnt)

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you very much! But I have more questions:
- is there possiblity to return more than one value?
- how I can apply that color to mColor that is a variable in class mainWindow?

Comment: It is not necessary to return more than one value, just create a getter method for each value you want to return: `if(colorPicker.exec() == ColorPicker::Accepted){
        setColor(colorPicker.color()); someType someVariable = colorPicker.getSomeValue(); someAnotherType someAnotherVariable =colorPicker.getAnotherValue(); ....
    }`

Comment: For the second question, create the methods and variables for those properties (similar in color to ColorPicker) and you can be accessed. Read about getters and setters methods. :P